# How to save current tab on refresh using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom tabs that work with javascript that allow me to select between tabs. But i am having trouble keeping the current tab open when submitting or refreshing the page. My javascript code only allows me to switch between tabs. I also attempted to create a local storage for the tabs but doesn't seem to be working.Any solutions?

```
<div class=" tab-pan row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="" style="font-size:36px; color:#333; text-align:center; line-height: 1.25em; ">Sign In To Your Account!</h1>
            <ul class="tab-login">
                <li rel="vouchpanel3" class="active">student</li>
                <li rel="vouchpanel4">teacher</li>
            </ul>
    <div id="vouchpanel3" class="pan active">

                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('customer.login') }}" style="margin-top:8%;">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="email" style="height:4rem;font-size:16px;font-weight:400" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        {{-- <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label> --}}

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="password" style="height:4rem; font-size:16px;font-weight:400" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <a class="btn btn-link" style="font-size:1.2rem; margin-left:-1%;" href="{{ route('customer.password.request') }}">
                                {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="loginandregister" style="width:100%; height:3rem; font-size:18px; padding:2px 0px 2px 0;">
                                Sign In
                            </button>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this code is switching from tab to tab
// im in the class tab-panels > ul tab-vouch > grabing the li
$('.tab-pan .tab-login li').on('click', function(){

    var $panels = $(this).closest('.tab-pan');
    $panels.find('.tab-login li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');



    var loginpanelshow = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.tab-pan .pan.active').stop().slideUp(300, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');

        $('#'+ loginpanelshow).slideDown(300, function(){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });

// this is the code that i attempted to use local storage to save on refresh
var relAtt = $(this).attr('rel');
    localStorage.setItem("current_tab", relAtt);
    console.log(relAtt);
$(document).ready(function(){
   var current_tab  = localStorage.getItem("current_tab");
   var element =  $(".tab-login li").find("[rel="+current_tab+"]").addClass('active');
    })
});

</script>
```

---

css

```
 <style>
    body{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .tab-login{
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .tab-login li{
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 3em;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tab-pan ul li.active{
        border-bottom: solid #CA3F3F;
        border-width:  0px 0 3px  ;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .tab-pan ul li{
        border-bottom: solid #d9d9d9;
        border-width:  0px 0 3px  ;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;

    }

    .tab-pan .pan{
        display: none;
    }
    .tab-pan .pan.active{
        display: block;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: @justDan no i dont get any errors in the console

Comment: Could you also add your css for that tab section?

Comment: @justDan added my css!

Comment: First of, don't put the `$(document).ready()` inside of your click callback. And try to put `console.log('get', localStorage.getItem("current_tab"));` inside it to actually see what is loaded from the local storage on document ready. Cause then you'll see that the storage is working as intended.

Comment: And then select the tab you wanna set active like this `$('li[rel="'+current_tab+'"]').addClass('active');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that your selector wasn't finding the right element. So from that click, I went up the DOM to get it's parent and then found the rel based on `current_tab`. Try this:

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gzhnrpj7/2/

HTML:

```
<div class=" tab-pan row justify-content-center">
  <ul class="tab-login">
    <li rel="vouchpanel3" class="vouchpanel3 active">student</li>
    <li rel="vouchpanel4" class="vouchpanel4">teacher</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
        background-color: white;
    }
    .tab-login{
        width: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .tab-login li{
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 3em;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        list-style: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tab-pan ul li.active{
        border-bottom: solid #CA3F3F;
        border-width:  0px 0 3px  ;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    .tab-pan ul li{
        border-bottom: solid #d9d9d9;
        border-width:  0px 0 3px  ;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;

    }

    .tab-pan .pan{
        display: none;
    }
    .tab-pan .pan.active{
        display: block;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-login li').removeClass('active');

    var current_tab = localStorage.getItem("current_tab"),
        element     = $(".tab-login li")
                      .parent('ul')
                      .find("[rel="+current_tab+"]")
                      .addClass('active');

  // this code is switching from tab to tab
  // im in the class tab-panels > ul tab-vouch > grabing the li
  $('.tab-pan .tab-login li').on('click', function() {
    var $panels = $(this).closest('.tab-pan');
    $panels.find('.tab-login li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var loginpanelshow = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.tab-pan .pan.active').stop().slideUp(300, function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $('#'+ loginpanelshow).slideDown(300, function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
    });

    // this is the code that i attempted to use local storage to save on refresh
    var relAtt = $(this).attr('rel');
    localStorage.setItem("current_tab", relAtt);
    console.log(relAtt);
    });
});
```

Click on the fiddle and the section will load. To test this you can open up your console, go to the Application tab, and click on Local Storage. When you click on one of the tabs and hit the refresh icon for local storage, you'll notice the value change from `vouchpanel3` to `vouchpanel4` or vice versa. Once you do click on a tab, you can further test that by simply running the jsfiddle again.

Comment: thank you! so much i been trying to get this to work all day @justDan

Comment: sorry i am replying late one more question! when i refresh the page the slider stays on current tab but the information changes back to the previous tag infomation @justDan

Comment: @jmike Ok so here's what you need to do. You would treat each section of content the same as your tabs. So say the teacher tab is loaded first based off of your local storage, you can also choose what content you'd like to show. If you can make a quick jsfiddle for me, I can help you out.

Comment: I'll also edit the fiddle I provided for a basic idea.

Comment: so basically like one form for the teacher and one form for the student and once i reload it stays on the correct form @justDan

Comment: sorry for all the messages here my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mikeshasaco/628m04wr/7/ @justDan

Comment: Mkay. give me a few minutes here.

Comment: @jmike Ok how about this: https://jsfiddle.net/628m04wr/14/. Same concept for displaying the active tab and now you also check with an `if` statement `onclick` to set the right `.pan`.

Comment: thank you! i really appreciate your help, any advice on how i can get better with javascript. @justDan

Comment: "Any advice on how I can get better with javascript". Code. Code a ton. Break stuff and fix it. You can read all day long and try to retain info, but to really get good you need to practice it. It's like wanting to get better at baseball. Unless you practice you can only go so far. https://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691 this was a book that helped me out a lot. Yes it's huge but read with it and code out examples. That's just one example book. There are also tons of other great resources. Oh and also, help out on SO more. It'll help you.

Comment: Thank you i will definitely get that book! @justDan

Comment: this is my final question my actually code had one more div tag which was `<div=class "col-md-8">` and it broke the entire program wondering what the fix here https://jsfiddle.net/mikeshasaco/628m04wr/24/ @justDan

Comment: @jmike For me to help out there I'd need to see the css for the whole layout of that section. Right now it is using the new `.col-md-8` class but there's no css reference to it. EDIT: hold on I think I see what's up.

Comment: @jmike Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/628m04wr/27/. Issue was the the input sections were looking for their old parent of `.tab-pan`, but when you added the new div, `.col-md-8` became it's parent.

Comment: hey Dan i got a quick question the javascript code you sent me works but when i delete my cache it doesn't load the code it like i have to refresh the page does it has something to do with the local storage. not sure why. @justDan

Comment: @jmike What's up dude. Easy fix here. Problem is when you clear your cache you remove the `localStorage` object so when the js looks for it, it throws an error and breaks. So what we can do is use the `||` operator give the `current_tab` var a default value if no `localStorage` item is found. Try this out: https://jsfiddle.net/628m04wr/28/